# CheckSum Calulation in a Sqlite Table

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am working on an embedded application in which I am storing data in a SqLite Database. To protect the integrity of the file I also required to produce a checksum for every row inserted. For now, I am calculating the checksum for a row by formating  the contents of column in a predefined format and also considering the checksum of the previous row. 
All things goes fine till here but problem is while verifying the checksum when the existing databases is opened. 
As it is a real time application and database can grow quite large, I don't have liberty for iterating the every row again. So my question is what can be the best way of verifying the checks um so that I need not to iterate every row?

Comment: Is “the previous row” really useful for the checksum? What if it gets deleted later?

Comment: @RolandIllig
Yes, actually I am extending a feature in the existing code in which checksum has been calculated in this way . And really it will be a problem if any row is deleted in the database but whatever I have understood from the current code yet I feel the deletion of row is not supported in the code..

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use PRAGMA integrity_check. Gathering its output will help to analyse correctness.

[PRAGMA integruty_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check)